# Django cannot load .wsgi as Python module

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I am trying to set up `Apache` and `Django`. I have the file `django.wsgi` at project root with the following content

```
import os
import sys

# activate virtualenv
activate_this = os.path.expanduser(
    "/var/www/continue/env-continue/bin/activate_this.py"
)
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

PROJECT_DIR = '/var/www/continue/'
APP_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'app',).replace('\\', '/'),

sys.path.append(APP_PATH)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings' # also tried 'continue.settings', but same errors appears

# import django.core.handlers.wsgi
# application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But I am getting the following error `Target WSGI script '/var/www/continue/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module` in the log file

> [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.273972 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036] mod_wsgi (pid=28781): Target WSGI script '/var/www/continue/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274014 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036] mod_wsgi (pid=28781): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/continue/django.wsgi'.
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274038 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274060 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/django.wsgi", line 18, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274137 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274152 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274174 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274186 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274211 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django import http
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274229 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274253 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.http.response import (HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse,
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274279 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274298 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274310 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274328 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274340 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 6, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274357 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.db import models
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274368 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/**init**.py", line 6, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274387 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch  # NOQA
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274404 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 13, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274435 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.db.models.fields import AutoField, Empty
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274454 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 15, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274489 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.db.models.lookups import default_lookups, RegisterLookupMixin
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274505 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 6, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274525 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from django.utils import timezone
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274536 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 13, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274554 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     import pytz
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274565 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/**init**.py", line 29, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274583 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     from pkg_resources import resource_stream
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274594 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2829, in 
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274612 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274622 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 440, in _build_master
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274639 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     ws = cls()
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274656 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 433, in **init**
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274674 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     self.add_entry(entry)
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274685 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in add_entry
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274701 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274712 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/var/www/continue/env-continue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1817, in find_distributions
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274728 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     importer = get_importer(path_item)
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274739 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 384, in get_importer
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274756 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036]     importer = path_hook(path_item)
>   [Wed Feb 18 14:28:28.274775 2015] [:error] [pid 28781:tid 140719897437952] [client 180.76.4.231:59036] TypeError: must be string, not tuple

I wonder what is going wrong?

Comment: `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'` I think you need add to 'settings' your project name: `'settings.your_project_name'`

Comment: @levi: do you mean `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "continue.settings"`?

Comment: @Lelouch... did you figure this out?